# Why find_element_by_xpath() taking 3 positional argument?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

*args unpacks the locators in tuple form.but is my case i have given only two arguments,but it is taking three arguments.Need help to understand.

I am newbie to selenium with python and played around some code from github,
but getting error.

TypeError: `find_element_by_xpath()` takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

```
locator.py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
class elements(object):
      Customer = (By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Customer')]")


base.py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class Page(object):
    def __init__(self,driver,url=None):
        self.url = url
        self.driver = driver

    def find_element_with_click(self,*locator):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(*locator).click()


pages.py
from selenium import webdriver
from base import Page
from locator import *

class CustomerCreation(Page):
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.locator = elements
        super().__init__(driver)

    def create_customer(self):
        self.driver.find_element_with_click(*self.locator.Customer)


testPages.py
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from pages import *
from locators import *
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class TestPages(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\ChromeDriver\chromedriver')
        cls.driver.get("#server")


    def test_tes_cust(self):
        page = CustomerCreation(self.driver)
        res_page = page.create_customer()          #Getting issue at this stage

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestPages)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

The error log:

> test_tes_cust (**main**.TestPages) ... ERROR
>     ======================================================================
>       ERROR: test_tes_cust (**main**.TestPages)
>       ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>           File "testPages.py", line 28, in test_tes_cust
>               res_page = page.create_customer()
>           File "C:\Users###\PycharmProjects\basics\pages.py", line 35, in create_customer
>               self.find_element_with_click(*self.locator.Customer)
>           File "C:\Users###\PycharmProjects\basics\base.py", line 21, in find_element_with_click
>               self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(*locator).click()
>       TypeError: find_element_by_xpath() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Answer (score 2):

You're passing one extra argument. Your arguments are:

1. `self`
2. `By.XPATH`
3. `"//button[contains(text(),'Customer')]"`

That's what you need to pass to `find_element` method. While `find_element_by_xpath` should take two arguments only:

1. `self`
2. `"//button[contains(text(),'Customer')]"`

So try to update your code as

```
def find_element_with_click(self,*locator):
    self.driver.find_element(*locator).click()
```

or you need to modify your `Customer` as:

```
Customer = "//button[contains(text(),'Customer')]"
```

and

```
def find_element_with_click(self, xpath):
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```